Can't see my smooth shading button in Dyntopo

Can't see my smooth shading button like everyone does in Dyntopo

Hello, it doesn't seem to exist anymore in Blender 4

As @moonboots said, it does not exist anymore - and actually I do not know why it was there in the first place. In older versions when I had the object shaded flat, the new faces added by Dyntopo were also flat, even with Smooth Shading enabled. And when the whole object was shaded smooth, the new faces were also smooth even with Smooth Shading in Dyntopo disabled.
